# Multiples-keys dictionary where key order doesn't matter

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary with two strings as a key and I want the keys to be in whatever order.

```
myDict[('A', 'B')] = 'something'
myDict[('B', 'A')] = 'something else'
print(myDict[('A', 'B')])
```

I want this piece of code to print 'something else'. Unfortunately, it seems that the ordering matters with tuples. What would be the best data structure to use as the key?

Comment: Why would you expect it to print that? `('A', 'B')` is mapped to `something`

Comment: If you want it to print `something else` then try `print(myDict[('B','A')])`

Comment: Well yeah, I do not expect it, but I want to use a data structure other than tuple which enables me to do that.

Comment: How would it know whether to choose `something` or `something else` then? Keys must be unique

Comment: Do you want it to switch the values in the tuple?

Comment: In other words - there is no way in Python to have the data structure omit the element ordering?

Comment: Why not just sort the tuples you are inserting?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)

Instead of a `tuple`, which is ordered, you can use a `frozenset`, which is *unordered*, while still *hashable* as `frozenset` is *immutable*.

```
myDict = {}
myDict[frozenset(('A', 'B'))] = 'something'
myDict[frozenset(('B', 'A'))] = 'something else'
print(myDict[frozenset(('A', 'B'))])
```

Which will print:

```
something else
```

---

---

Unfortunately, this simplicity comes with a disadvantage, since `frozenset` is basically a “frozen” set. There will be no duplicate values in the `frozenset`, for example,

```
frozenset((1, 2)) == frozenset((1,2,2,1,1))
```

If the trimming down of values doesn’t bother you, feel free to use `frozenset`

But if you’re 100% sure that you don’t want what was mentioned above to happen, there are however two alternates:

---

*First* method is to use a `Counter`, and make it `hashable` by using `frozenset` again: (**Note: everything in the tuple must be *hashable***)

```
from collections import Counter

myDict = {}
myDict[frozenset(Counter(('A', 'B')).items())] = 'something'
myDict[frozenset(Counter(('B', 'A')).items())] = 'something else'
print(myDict[frozenset(Counter(('A', 'B')).items())])

# something else
```

---

*Second* method is to use the built-in function `sorted`, and make it *hashable* by making it a `tuple`. This will sort the values before being used as a key: (**Note: everything in the tuple must be *sortable* and *hashable***)

```
myDict = {}
myDict[tuple(sorted(('A', 'B')))] = 'something'
myDict[tuple(sorted(('B', 'A')))] = 'something else'
print(myDict[tuple(sorted(('A', 'B')))])

# something else
```

But if the tuple elements are neither all *hashable*, nor are they all *sortable*, unfortunately, you might be out of luck and need to create your own dict structure... D:

Comment: Your `frozenset(Counter(…))` code is wrong: `frozenset(Counter('abc'))`, `frozenset(Counter('abbccc'))`, and `frozenset(('a', 'b', 'c'))` are all equal. You want `frozenset(Counter(xs).iteritems())` (`.items()` in Python 3).

Comment: Also, if the elements aren't hashable, then `tuple(sorted(xs))` will still not be a valid key, because it won't itself be hashable: if `xs == [[1], [2]]`, for example, then `tuple(sorted(xs)) == ([1], [2])`, which also yields an error when you use it as a key. It kind of sounds like what you're trying to say is `json.dumps(xs, sort_keys=True)`, but honestly I can't imagine a situation where marshalling live objects to keys every time that you want to look them up in a dictionary is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own structure:

```
class ReverseDict:
   def __init__(self):
      self.d = {}
   def __setitem__(self, k, v):
      self.d[k] = v

   def __getitem__(self, tup):
      return self.d[tup[::-1]]

myDict = ReverseDict()
myDict[('A', 'B')] = 'something'
myDict[('B', 'A')] = 'something else'
print(myDict[('A', 'B')])
```

Output:

```
something else
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the point here is that the elements of the tuple point to the same dictionary element regardless of their order. This can be done by making the hash function commutative over the tuple key elements:

```
class UnorderedKeyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *arg):
        if arg:
            for k,v in arg[0].items():
                self[k] = v

    def _hash(self, tup):
        return sum([hash(ti) for ti in tup])

    def __setitem__(self, tup, value):
        super().__setitem__(self._hash(tup), value)

    def __getitem__(self, tup):
      return super().__getitem__(self._hash(tup))

mydict = UnorderedKeyDict({('a','b'):12,('b','c'):13})
mydict[('b','a')]
    >> 12
```